# How to use conditional Eval inside Repeater control?

Tags: asp.net

How to use conditional Eval inside Repeater control in this case:

```
if Actions.ShowDates(Eval("DatesAsPeriod").ToString(), Eval("DateList").ToString().Length) > 0
then show this:
    <a href="Details.aspx?ActionID=<%# Eval("ID") %>"><%# Eval("Artist") %></a>
else show this:
    <%# Eval("Artist") %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to wrap `if` statements in code tags:

```
<% if (Actions.ShowDates(Eval("DatesAsPeriod").ToString(), Eval("DateList").ToString().Length) > 0)
   {
%>
    <a href="Details.aspx?ActionID=<%# Eval("ID") %>"><%# Eval("Artist") %></a>
<%
   }
   else
   {
%>
   <%# Eval("Artist") %>
<%
   }
%>
```

Inside a repeater, you should be able to use this:

```
<%# (Actions.ShowDates(Eval("DatesAsPeriod").ToString(), Eval("DateList").ToString()).Length > 0) ? "<a href="Details.aspx?ActionID='" + Eval("ID") + "'>" + Eval("Artist") + "</a>" : Eval("Artist") %>
```

Comment: I use this inside Repeater control and got the following error:

Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control.

Comment: You have to inline that. Can you try the second code?

Comment: Here's my code, but there something's wrong with syntax:

<%# (Actions.ShowDates(Eval("DatesAsPeriod").ToString(), Eval("DateList").ToString()).Length > 0) ? "<a href="Details.aspx?ActionID='<%# Eval("ID") %>'>" + Eval("Artist") + "</a>" : Eval("Artist") %>

Comment: It doesn't work.

Please, pay attention ShowDates method returns string and I need the length of it. There's an extra curly brace.

Comment: It complaints about syntax: Expression expected.

Comment: I fixed it:

<%# (Actions.ShowDates(Eval("DatesAsPeriod").ToString(), Eval("DateList").ToString()).Length > 0) ? "<a href='Details.aspx?ActionID='" + Eval("ID") + "'>" + Eval("Artist") + "</a>" : Eval("Artist") %

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap it into placeholders

```
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" 
  Visible='<%# Actions.ShowDates(Eval("DatesAsPeriod").ToString(), Eval("DateList").ToString().Length) > 0 %>'>
  <a href="Details.aspx?ActionID=<%# Eval("ID") %>"><%# Eval("Artist") %></a> 
</asp:PlaceHolder>
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server"
  Visible='<%# Actions.ShowDates(Eval("DatesAsPeriod").ToString(), Eval("DateList").ToString().Length) == 0 %>'>
  <%# Eval("Artist") %>
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```